# Calculating data dependent on non-committed (state) data of child/distant components in React

Tags: reactjs

TL;DR edit in retrospect years later: there's no solution that's not gross as long as it's just state data - you'll need to also get it into a separate store somewhere somehow and can do whatever you want at that point. But read the question and the answer and the back-and-forth if you want some more background.

---

I have a table of two sections, each with various input values. Let's say that it is a survey. Feeding data into this is straightforward; I have the typical model:

```
{ "sections": [ { "name": "a", values: { "A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 1, ... } }, ... ], ... }
```

And a component hierarchy like:

```
<Survey>
  <Section> (for each section)
    <ValueRow> (for each value)
```

I put the model into a prop on the survey and the right information is trickled down into the subcomponents. Each `ValueRow` has a text field and its ephemeral value reflected back into its own state. This works fine "on the way down", in the one way flow that React is built for.

However, I also wish to show progress on the `Section` level and for the entire `Survey`, both simple things like number of fields filled out and statistical data needing the entire data set - what's the average across sections, how many "1" answers do I have in total, what's my grade (calculated from all the answers) and so on. Essentially, I'd also want to have:

```
<Survey>
  <SurveyWideStats>
  <Section> (for each section)
    <SectionWideStats>
    <ValueRow> (for each value)
```

This turns into a reduction of the current state instead of the model data. What's the best way of doing this in React? Flux and Actions and Stores all seem to deal with how to handle the data once it has been committed to the model. What I want to do is to pluck all the state data and do something with it, but it also seems terribly gross for the `SurveyWideStats` element, for example, to go poking through the <s>garbage</s>state of its sibling element's children.

My current solution is to pass around an accumulation object and provide enough state to each component that it can keep calling that whenever something changes. This seems clear and divided enough, but it means that I have to have two passes and have to be careful not to start fiddling with state during rendering (at least since that's when I call the accumulation object - I suppose there may be a better point during the lifecycle where I could call that). And in addition, it seems like this would be an obstacle to "pick up from" server side rendering.

What's the best way? Is there an established pattern for this - preferably one where these things don't have to be so custom and really tailored to the data all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to do this:

1. Pass the entire table as a prop to the highest component .
   Inside survey's render function, calculate the stats, then pass them to the  component as props, followed by the foreach loops over the table for the other children components. That way, your stats component is a pure component, does not need state and does not need to poke in siblings.
2. Create a stats function in a store, and have the  component call this to get the stats. NB best not to save the stats in a store, since it is clearly derived data. Unless for performance reasons.

Hope this helps!

UPDATE:
To handle changes by the user when they change an input value, you have two options, depending on your preference:

(Option 1 describes a pure component).

1. (When you use flux pattern): Put the value of the input control in props. And whenever the user makes a change, fire an action to update a store, and have the store pass down updated props. So the (top) component notices a change event and rerenders. This creates more or less 'live' updates, e.g. when a user types a single character in an input field, the page title is updated immediately. The component with the input control does not have (and does not need) setState. This setup may become slow in really large component trees (because with each character, the entire tree is rerendered). But react is superfast and smartly only renders changes in de tree.
2. Put the initial prop value in state (in getInitialState() and put the input value in state also. Typical example: user types a character in an input field, the change triggers a setState() and the component is rendered again. Only when the user clicks some save or commit button, an action is fired to save the value in a store.

UPDATE:
As a bonus, below the flow for updating stores and components.
[image: Flux Flow for updates and stats]

Comment: Both of these mean that I shouldn't use `setState` when I change the value in `ValueRow`'s input control, right? What should I do instead?

Comment: 2. is basically what I do now, so 1. would solve the problem of having to peek in state, I'd just have to look in the model (which is what trickles down through the props). But this means that 2. will only really work up to a point and that state should be avoided in favor of props to not make things like this harder - is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it is good practice to avoid state in favor of props. State lives inside the component (and maybe passed down as props to children). But parent component can never know state directly (so no 'peeking'). The only way to tell parent about state change (e.g. user clicks save button) is to go full-circle: stateful child fires action -> stores are updated and emit change -> parent component reads store and re-renders children -> children get new props. (if you want the stateful child to do something with the new props, you need a componentWillReceiveProps function to update state)

Comment: Right, this jibes well with my intuition for this. What didn't jibe was my idea of not committing anything to the model object until a save happens, but I guess if I make the distinction between a Store holding the model objects for the UI and eventually sending the model to the server and its persistence, it all works out. But that also means the Store has to have actions mirroring changing every "leaf" that is manipulable by the editors on the model.

Comment: @Jesper. As long as only component itself and its children need to know about state, you can put it in state. As soon as any parent component or store or server need to know about a change, you need to send off an action to tell the world. I'm not sure what you mean with 'Store has to have actions mirroring changing every "leaf" that is manipulable by the editors on the model'

Comment: I mean that when the Store needs to be the keeper of the model, changing one answer in one section in this survey surely means there has to be one action for doing that - right? The alternative is for the answer editor (`ValueRow` in this case, the React component rendering the input field) to know to clone the existing model, change its value and tell the store that the entire model changed, which sounds wrong. This is what I mean when I say that `ValueRow` edits a "leaf" on the model, not the entire model.

Comment: Oh I see. Typical setup would be: ValueRow sends 1 myValueHasChangedTo Action -> low-level store + stat store listen to this action: the corresponding low-level store updates -> the store holding the stats has WaitFor for the lower-level stores, then emits change (stats are derived data, so probably not stored in the store) -> the top-level component listens to stats store and retrieves all stats from stat store -> stat store gets all details from lower level stores and delivers stats to top-level component -> top-level component re-renders and sends new stats to lower-level components.

Comment: That sounds like the kind of confusing explanation that's likely the correct one ;). Put it in your answer and I'll mark it as the answer! Thanks again for the help.